# Describe the best practices to make data correlation simple in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, correlation

What's the best strategy when doing data correlation with jmeter? I have some ideas/questions, that go along these lines: usage of automatic correlation solutions (http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/automatic-correlation-for-jmeter-td5531399.html), usage of post processing extractors that best suite the need, for example regexp for http headers, xpath exp for HTML, if using xpath, get assistance by using Firebug or similar plugins, usage of xpath vs css&jquery, don't correlate data that isn't checked on the server, for example, if http referer is not controlled, it would be a waiste of time to correlate it, ... and such, but I would like to hear from more experienced people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't have autocorrelation. However you have tools like JCorrelate to accomplish the same. JMX Enhancers have some good tools that can help you cut your JMeter scripting time by 95%. Vist www.jmxenhancer.com for more details.

On the other hand, Blazemeter also have Smart JMX in their plugin which gives us autocorrelated scripts.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no auto-correlation for JMeter. HP Loadrunner has this functionality however it often fails.
2. XPath vs CSS/JQuery:

   - if your page has a very complex DOM and low number of styles - go for CSS
   - if DOM of your page is simple and styles number is high - go for XPath
3. If you simulating a real user using real browser - JMeter test should replicate it as close as possible, so make sure that you have:

   - [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
   - [HTTP Cache Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager)
   - [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
   - [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configured to:

     - Retrieve all embedded resources
     - Use concurrent pool of 2-5 threads for it
     - Filter out any external domains via "URLs must match" input